SUM of a range of durations in an XLSX-Formatted sheet always returns 0 or errors
Excel document
I have the following XLSX-formatted spreadsheet in Google Sheets
I'm trying to set a formula on cell R5 (colored in red) so that it adds up all the times in the range L4:N42 but whatever I try it I either get 00:00:00 or all kinds of errors, not even chatGPT can help.
Current Formula
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(L4:N42);L4:N42;0)));1;1)



Though it's understandable why one would post a document, for security, it would be better to post data type of the cells, with perhaps a screenshot  of the data.

Please, don't post a screenshot use this VBA code or use this website to create a Markdown table and edit it into your question.

Welcome @MoRryN! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

And if the answer works for you, please tick it!

Your formula shouldn't include ARRAY_CONSTRAIN. That aside, the main reason the formula will always return a 0 is that the condition checks for numbers in the range and returns zero for everything else, but all your durations are formatted as text strings, not numbers.
It is a simple matter to coerce numbers-as-strings back to numbers by using them in a calculation, and you can also use a single array function, SUMPRODUCT, to return your desired result:
=SUMPRODUCT(L4:N42*1) 


The first one gave me an error but =SUMPRODUCT(L4:N42*1)  as simple as that worked so I guess I was just overthinking.
Thank you very much!!

@MoRryN The first one is a reiteration of yours, it isn't part of the solution. I've suggested an edit to the question to include the formula and removed it from the answer to avoid any further confusion.
